# Constantine and "suicide == no Catholic burial"

Tags: dc, constantine-2005

As one might recall from *Constantine*, a plot point was that Isabel Dodson was a suicide and thus barred from a Catholic burial, condemned to Hell, et cetera.

After some cursory research I found [this article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/31350305) which states:

> Broad shifts in the cultural attitude towards suicide, due in large
>   part to new understandings of mental illness as disease, had a
>   powerful effect on Catholic thought and practice in modernity, and **the
>   Church eventually dropped the ban on funerals for suicides from its
>   law code altogether in the 1980s**.

So I find myself wondering if this is a plot hole.  Specifically, the "no Catholic burial" part -- the theological question of whether Isabel ended up in Hell either way is beyond the scope of what I'm interested in here.

A few specific details I'm interested in include:

- Is there anything in the movie that would give the viewer a strong hint one way or the other as to whether the events are set during, before, or after 'the 1980s'?
- Would it be within the scope of powers of that Church official that Angela spoke to (alas, his specific office escapes me at the moment) to make his own ruling on the issue?

Supporting evidence from the comics, the novelization of the movie, etc, is welcome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Would it be within the scope of powers of that Church official that Angela spoke to (alas, his specific office escapes me at the moment) to make his own ruling on the issue?

Yes, see [here](https://classroom.synonym.com/funerals-due-to-suicide-the-roman-catholic-church-12085229.html) for more information. It is left up to local authorities.

> However, according to the Global Catholic Network, although the Catholic Church's official stance has changed, the Church does not force priests to hold funerals for suicide victims, and in many cases, the final decision about the funeral is made by a local bishop.

Comment: There is a pretty good Q&A on this [at Christianity.SE if you want to cross link that as well](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1217/24204)